# Update Table Item Quantity

Tags: vue.js

Guys I'm starting with Vue and I'm having a little difficulty. In the image below I have a table with some items and when I will increase the amount of the item Orange for example is increased all other items, how to fix it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbNTs.png)

My code

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
        return {
            quantity: 1,
            fruits: [
                { Code: 1, Name: 'Abacaxi', Price: "50.00" },
                { Code: 2, Name: 'Abacate', Price: "50.00" },
                { Code: 3, Name: 'Morango', Price: "60.00" },
                { Code: 4, Name: 'Maçã', Price: "17.00" },
                { Code: 5, Name: 'Laranja', Price: "30.00" }
            ]
        }
    },

    methods: {
      add() {
          this.quantity++
      },
      
      remove() {
          if(this.quantity === 0) {
              this.quantity = 0
          } else {
              this.quantity--
          }
      }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <template>
    <div class="user-list">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#Code</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr v-for="fruit in fruits" :key="fruit.Code">
                    <td>
                        <button @click="remove">-</button>
                        <input type="text" :value="quantity">
                        <button @click="add">+</button>
                    </td>
                    <td>{{ fruit.Name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ fruit.Price }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</template>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just need to have a `quantity` on each item in your list. You'd then pass the relevant item to `add` or `remove`.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
        return {
            fruits: [
                { Code: 1, Name: 'Abacaxi', Price: "50.00", quantity: 1 },
                { Code: 2, Name: 'Abacate', Price: "50.00", quantity: 1 },
                { Code: 3, Name: 'Morango', Price: "60.00", quantity: 1 },
                { Code: 4, Name: 'Maçã', Price: "17.00", quantity: 1 },
                { Code: 5, Name: 'Laranja', Price: "30.00", quantity: 1 }
            ]
        }
    },

    methods: {
      add(fruit) {
          fruit.quantity++
      },
      
      remove(fruit) {
          if(fruit.quantity !== 0) {
              fruit.quantity--
          }
      }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <template>
    <div class="user-list">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#Code</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr v-for="fruit in fruits" :key="fruit.Code">
                    <td>
                        <button @click="remove(fruit)">-</button>
                        <input type="text" v-model.number="fruit.quantity">
                        <button @click="add(fruit)">+</button>
                    </td>
                    <td>{{ fruit.Name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ fruit.Price }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</template>
</div>
```

I've also switched `:value` to `v-model.number`, which seems more likely to be what you'd want though it's not directly related to the problem mentioned in the question.